# Hiding (and re-showing) cards in RecyclerView backed by Cursor

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cursoradapter

I have a RecyclerView with CursorAdapter implemented as shown here: https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59

I also have a ItemTouchHelper attached to recycler implemented this way (don't mind my Snackbar modifications):

```
private class TouchHelperCallbacks extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {

        public TouchHelperCallbacks(int dragDirs, int swipeDirs) {
            super(dragDirs, swipeDirs);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                              RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            Snackbar.make(recycler,
                          R.string.course_hidden,
                          Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setOnHideListener(new Snackbar.OnHideListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onHide() {
                            //after Snackbar disappears, either because of a 
                            //timeout or it is swiped away, remove item from db 
                        }
                    })
                    .setAction(R.string.undo,
                               new View.OnClickListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       //put card back into the recycler
                                   }
                               })
                    .setActionTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.color_accent))
                    .colorTheFuckingTextToWhite(getActivity())
                    .doStuffThatGoogleDidntFuckingDoProperly(getActivity(), null)
                    .show();
        }
    }
```

The card gets swiped away properly, but instead of cards below it lifting up, there is only blank space left where the swiped card used to be. If I call `notifyDatasetChanged()` while Snackbar is showing, it will reappear at its previous spot.

I'd like to avoid accessing database and make undo as lightweight as possible. I could implement an extra column or delete/insert rows while Snackbar is still showing, but it seems too heavy for such a simple task (3-4 queries in a few seconds).

Ideally, I'd like to access ViewHolders that are currently on screen and translate them by desired height, and if user chooses to undo, do the same thing, but in opposite direction and insert the card back.

`viewHolder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE)` doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Have you tried using an ArrayList populated from the DB as the data set? that way you can make shallow changes to the ArrayList and call notifyDatasetChanged then only commit those changes to the database when you feel like it.

Comment: Yeah, that would certainly be possible. I'll try it out if querying database ends up being a performance hit with moderate datasets (I'm not sure how caching exactly works with Loaders and Cursors). Until then, I guess I'll just be annoyed because I don't have complete control over my app

Comment: Just out of curiosity: is it the adapter's or recycler's job to manipulate view holders and views?

Answer (score 1):

The code at https://github.com/brnunes/SwipeableRecyclerView does exactly what you want.

This is how I implemented it:

```
private RecyclerView rvRoutes;
(...)

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            rvRoutes = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvRoutes);
           (...)

            SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener swipeTouchListener =
                    new SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener(rvRoutes,
                            new SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener.SwipeListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean canSwipeLeft(int position) {   return true;   }

                                @Override
                                public boolean canSwipeRight(int position) {   return true;  }

                                @Override
                                public void onDismissedBySwipeLeft(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                                    for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mItems.get(position) + " swiped left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onDismissedBySwipeRight(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                                    for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mItems.get(position) + " swiped right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            });

            rvRoutes.addOnItemTouchListener(swipeTouchListener);
```

}

That's all it takes, since all the animations to move items up, down, etc, are in the SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener class.